# Inherit height from parent with box-sizing: border-box

Tags: css

Here is the deal.
I have parent div with css like:

```
.parent{box-sizing: border-box; height: 60px; border: 1px solid green;}
```

Child div with css:

```
.child{height:inherit;background: red}
```

Here is markup:

```css
.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.child {
  height:inherit;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CheWebDev/fcecuvut/1/

So how to get inherit height from parent? Is it possible with box-sizing: border-box prop.?

Comment: Can't you use height: 100% instead?

Comment: Thanks! Straight to the point! Very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using `height: 100%`. As this is basicly the same as setting `height: inherit`. Where `height: inherit` makes it the exact height as its parent, `height: 100%` will make it based on the parent rules.

So if a padding isset (in your case a border), it will not overflow the padding. But only fills the available height of its parent.

```css
.parent{box-sizing: border-box; height: 60px; border: 10px solid green;}
.child{height:100%;background: red}
```

```html
   <div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

Comment: No problem, can happen ;)